# Intellij IDEA 2020.1 how to navigate the cursor to the next/previous statement?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is a shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down -> this navigates the cursor to the next line, not the next statement. when i have many lines in a statement, say, i am constructing an instance of an object using builder pattern or using java 8 streams, one typically will have many lines as part of a single statement ending with semicolon. In this case, if i am in the first line of the statement, my required shortcut should jump the cursor to the next statement starting after the semicolon of the current multiline statement. Is there a shortcut for this ?

Comment: The question is confusing, do you want to move the statement block or cursor?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, edited for clarity : i want to move the cursor, not the block